# NSURLConnection didReceiveData not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I've read through tons of messages saying the same thing all over again : when you use a NSURLConnection, delegate methods are *not called*. I understand that Apple's doc are incomplete and reference deprecated methods, which is a shame, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Code for the request is there :

```
// Create request
NSURL *urlObj = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlObj cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

if (![NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't handle request...");
    return;
}

// Start connection
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES]; // Edited
});
```

...and code for the delegate methods is here :

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Receiving response: %@, status %d", [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response allHeaderFields], [(NSHTTPURLResponse*) response statusCode]);
    self.data = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", error);
    [self _finish];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)_data {
    [data appendData:_data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)_connection destinationURL:(NSURL *) destinationURL {
    NSLog(@"Connection done!");
    [self _finish];
}
```

There's not a lot of error checking here, but I've made sure of a few things :

- Whatever happens, `didReceiveData` is **never** called, so I don't get any data
- ...but the data is transfered (I checked using `tcpdump`)
- ...and the other methods are called successfully.
- If I use the `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate` instead of `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, everything works but I can't get a hold on the downloaded file (this is a known bug)
- The request is not deallocated before completion by bad memory management
- Nothing changes if I use a standard HTML page somewhere on the internet as my URL
- The request is kicked off from the main queue

I don't want to use a third-party library, as, ultimately, these requests are to be included in a library of my own, and I'd like to minimize the dependencies. If I have to, I'll use `CFNetwork` directly, but it will be a huge pain in the you-know-what.

If you have any idea, it would help greatly. Thanks!

Comment: did you check with an NSLog() inside of didReceiveData?

Comment: Yup, NSLog _and_ breakpoints, nothing is called...

Comment: try putting in the mainRunLoop?

Comment: @JesseGumpo: This is what `dispatch_async` does, right? Unless I'm very much mistaken, in which case I apologize...

Comment: @Dima : Tried, didn't work... And `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` is a sub-protocol of `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, so it wouldn't be very different...

Comment: where are the delegate methods? in a viewController?

Comment: Nope, in another class, which is retained by a view controller for safety.

Comment: well you could always use [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...

Comment: Mmmh, probably, yeah. I'm used to delegates, so I dismissed it, but perhaps this is the way to go!

Comment: OK, this works. If you want to edit your answer, I'll accept it. But it would have been great to track the progress of the download, and I can't do that without the delegate methods...

Comment: The only thing left I can think of, since everything else is getting called, is a typo in the -(void) didReceiveData line.  Is that copied exactly?

Comment: Yup. Anyway, I'll make things work without getting the progress, and then will try to make it work with it!

Comment: I think this sort of problem is really worth tracking down (rather than trying to work around).  This _should_ work, if it doesn't it might hint at stranger things going on in your code.  I notice you've changed the delegate arguments slightly, perhaps C&P them directly in from the documentation, or write a clean class and try in that, etc. This really should work, so find out why it isn't rather than burying the problem in a work-around.

Comment: @ChrisH: For now I'd rather have something that works, even if it's a one-legged weird beast, and then I'll track it down. I spent one full day on this, so I'm leaving it to rest hoping the solution will come to me!

Comment: ok well good luck - just on the off-chance, in the code above the didreceivedata callback is the only one without an nslog() - you're sure it's not being called though, right?

Comment: @ChrisH: Yup, cf. my previous comments, I had a breakpoint _and_ a `NSLog` before, just forgot to put them back before copy/pasting ;)

Comment: - (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading: belongs to NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate, if you implement it, didReceiveData: will not be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the sendAsynchronousRequest method.. there's less information during the connection, but the code is a lot cleaner.

```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
        if (data){
            //do something with data
        }
        else if (error)
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
```

From Apple:

> By default, a connection is scheduled on the current thread in the
>   default mode when it is created. If you create a connection with the
>   initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method and provide NO for
>   the startImmediately parameter, you can schedule the connection on a
>   different run loop or mode before starting it with the start method.
>   You can schedule a connection on multiple run loops and modes, or on
>   the same run loop in multiple modes.

Unless there is a reason to explicitly run it in [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop],
you can remove these two lines:

```
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[connection start];
```

or change the mode to NSDefaultRunLoopMode

Comment: You're actually right, but it doesn't change anything... ;( I edited my code though! I'm not sure I have knowledge beyond the basics when it comes to run loops and queues, so tell me if I'm not doing something right!

Comment: you can either do: [..initWithRequest:() delegate:()] OR [..initWithRequest:() delegate:() startImmediately:()] and include the [..scheduleIn..]

Comment: From my understanding (cf. my code), if you put `startImmediately:YES`, it should work. But it doesn't, Apple's docs are a mess on this...

Comment: Not only did this resolve the problem described, it also got rid of what seemed to be leak induced by calling the methods I was using.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same problem. Very annoying, but it seems that if you implement this method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
```

Then `connection:didReceiveData:` will never be called. You have to use `connectionDidFinishLoading:` instead... Yes, the docs say it is deprecated, but I think thats only because this method moved from `NSURLConnectionDelegate` into `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`.

Comment: You saved me!  How unexpected!

Comment: This was the exact thing I needed to do.  I naively implemented `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, and `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate`, thinking those three would give me the greatest amount of information for me to relay to my user about data download progress and implemented the methods it was warning me I needed.  You do NOT need `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate` if you are using `didReceiveData`

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection API says " ..delegate methods are called **on the thread** that started the asynchronous load operation for the associated NSURLConnection object."

Because dispatch_async will start new thread, and NSURLConnection will not pass to that other threat the call backs, so **do not use dispatch_async** with NSURLConnection.

You do not have to afraid about frozen user interface, NSURLConnection providing only the controls of asynchronous loads.

If you have **more files to download**, you can start some of connection in first turn, and later they finished, in the connectionDidFinishLoading: method you can start new connections.

```
int i=0;
for (RetrieveOneDocument *doc in self.documents) {

    if (i<5) {
         [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        i++;
    }
}

..

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    ii++;
    if(ii == 5) {
         [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        ii=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `dispatch_async` does not necessarily start a new thread (e.g. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {})` runs the block on the main thread.) But your point about the callbacks happening on the current thread was exactly my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the outgoing `NSURLRequest` has been setup to have a `-HTTPMethod` of `HEAD`. Quite hard to do that by accident though!