# Error in using asynhronous request in iOS%?

Tags: ios, web-services, asynchronous, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I have done web services using synchronous request, using the following code,

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:"\\urlString"];
NSMutableURLRequest * request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSError * error;
NSURLResponse * response;
NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"data is %@",data);
NSString * outputData=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                  NSLog(@"output is %@",outputData);
```

This was successful and gave me the perfect output,

Now I changed to ASynchronous,

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:"\\urlString"];
NSMutableURLRequest * request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse * response;
 output=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response : %@",output);


request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *requestBodyData = [output dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

(void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Then delegates,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"response from connection %@",response);
 responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
{
NSLog(@"Stream finished.");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)outputData {
// Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
[responseData appendData:outputData];

output=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"Response data is output %@",output);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Error occured");
}
```

But, here the didReceiveData method is not called. Please give me a clue

Comment: In particular this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15440151/1187415 seems to answer your question.

Comment: I have tried all the answers in stack overflow, then too, I cant get the answer

Comment: According to the answer that I linked to, you should *replace* your `connectionDidFinishDownloading: destinationURL:` method by a `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method. - Did you try that?

Comment: i tried that, now connectionDidFinishLoading: is not called

Comment: Are the other delegate method called now? (didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData)

Comment: didReceiveResponse, is called

Comment: What about `connection:didFailWithError:`? You should implement that as well.

Comment: I have implemented it, I didn't posted all the methods in my question

Comment: Either `connection:didFailWithError:` or `connectionDidFinishLoading:` should be called. Can you add your updated code to the question?

Comment: ConnectionDidFinishLoading: method is called, it moves to next screen, with out moving to DidReceiveData

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: didReceiveResponse is called and connectionDidFinishLoading is called. That means that your server did not send any data. (didReceiveData will not be called *after* connectionDidFinishLoading.)

Comment: (didReceiveData will not be called after connectionDidFinishLoading.) what is this statement, brief it

Comment: didReceiveResponse is called first. Then didReceiveData is called one or more times. connectionDidFinishLoading is called last. - Did you *remove* the connectionDidFinishDownloading: destinationURL: method?